# SQL - Select from database where ID is present more than x times

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `users` in my database, it have the following structure:

```
id (int)
username (varchar)
upline (int)
```

Now, if a user is a referral to another user, it's `id` will be insterted into `upline`

My question is, how can I search, generally across my entire users table, for the users who have the same `id` inserted into `upline`, without having a specific `id`?

Comment: What does $1 represent?

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  What do you mean "inserted into upline"?

Comment: A specific argument. I'm worried you have a denormalized table. Is `upline` a list? There's a difference between user having list of ids he's a referral of and each user having his referral id.

Comment: "upline" just contains either "0" or the referral users "id". I just want to find the users who have example 100 referrals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you basically just want a `having` clause:

```
select upline, group_concat(id)
from users
where upline <> 0
group by upline
having count(*) = 100;
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!